# Given beginning and end dates with a specific year, what is the best way to fill in the date column of a dataframe that only contains day and month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I am parsing bank statement PDFs that have the full start and end dates in question both in the filename and in the document, but the actual entries corresponding to the transactions only contain the day and month ('%d %b'). Here is what the series looks like for the "Date" column:

```
1           
2     24 Dec
3     27 Dec
4           
5           
6     30 Dec
7           
8     31 Dec
9           
10          
11     2 Jan
12          
13     3 Jan
14     6 Jan
15    14 Jan
16    15 Jan
```

I have the start and end dates as 2013-12-23 and 2014-01-23. What is an efficient way to populate this series/column with the correct full date given the start and end range? I would like any existing date to forward fill the same date to the next date so:

```
1           
2     24 Dec 2013
3     27 Dec 2013
4     27 Dec 2013 
5     27 Dec 2013 
6     30 Dec 2013
7     30 Dec 2013 
8     31 Dec 2013
9     31 Dec 2013 
10    31 Dec 2013     
11     2 Jan 2014
12     2 Jan 2014    
13     3 Jan 2014
14     6 Jan 2014
15    14 Jan 2014
16    15 Jan 2014
```

The date format is irrelevant as long as it is a datetime format. I was hoping to use something internal to pandas, but I can't figure out what to use and right now a check against the start and end dates and filling out the year based on where the date fits into the range is the best I've come up with, but it is inefficient to have to run this on the whole column. Any help/advice/tips would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: just wanted to add that I am hoping for a general procedural solution that can apply to any start/end date and set of transactions and not just this particular series included although I think this is a good test case as it has an end of year overlap.

EDIT2: what I have so far after posting this question is the following, which doesn't seem terribly efficient, but seems to work:

```
def add_year(date, start, end):
    if not date:
        return(np.NaN)
    else:
        test_date = "{} {}".format(date, start.year)
        test_date = datetime.strptime(test_date, '%d %b %Y').date()
        if start_date <= test_date <= end_date:
            return(test_date)
        else:
            return(datetime.strptime("{} {}".format(date, end.year), '%d %b %Y').date())

df['Date'] = df.Date.map(lambda date: add_year(date, start_date, end_date))
df.Date.ffill(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].replace('nan|NaN',float('NaN'),regex=True)
#convert string nan to actual NaN's
df['Date']=df['Date'].ffill()
#forword fill NaN's
c=df['Date'].str.contains('Dec') & df['Date'].notna()
#checking if Date column contain Dec
idx=df[c].index[-1]
#getting the index of last 'Date' where condition c satisfies
df.loc[:idx,'Date']=df.loc[:idx,'Date']+' 2013'
#adding 2013 to 'Date' upto last index of c
df.loc[idx+1:,'Date']=df.loc[idx+1:,'Date']+' 2014'
#adding 2014 to 'Date' from last index of c+1 upto last
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#Finally converting these values to datetime
```

output of `df`:

```
    Date
0   NaT
1   2013-12-24
2   2013-12-27
3   2013-12-27
4   2013-12-27
5   2013-12-30
6   2013-12-30
7   2013-12-31
8   2013-12-31
9   2013-12-31
10  2014-01-02
11  2014-01-02
12  2014-01-03
13  2014-01-06
14  2014-01-14
15  2014-01-15
```

Comment: hi Anurag, thanks a lot for this contribution, it definitely works for this particular example, but I neglected to mention that I have many date ranges and transaction entries, so was hoping for a more procedural solution that can apply to any start/end date and set of transactions. I'll add that to the question in an edit. I have a solution just now, but it doesn't seem terribly efficient using a map and function to check the dates, thanks!